# Jquery Mobile pagecreate function never completes

Tags: jquery-mobile, initialization

I am using the pagecreate initialization event to call a function which makes an AJAX call to populate a list.

The problem I have is that this event never completes. The page loading message persists.

I've search here and on the Jquery forum, without any luck.

My code looks like this:

```
$( "#events" ).live( 'pagecreate', function(event) {
    // Executed once the page is loaded
    var fromDate = new Date(),
        toDate = new Date(fromDate.getFullYear(), fromDate.getMonth() + 3, fromDate.getDate());
    update(fromDate, toDate);
    //alert('done');
});


function update(from, to) {

    var eventList = $('ul#event-list');

    $.ajax({
      url: 'events.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {from: from, to: to},
      success: function(data) { 
        showEvents(data, from, to, eventList); // Create list items and append to eventList
        $('.value h2').formatCurrency({ negativeFormat: "-%s%n" }); // Format currency correctly using jQuery plugin
        }
    }); 
}
```

I get an "a.Deferred is not a function" error, which suggests to me it has something to do with the completion of the AJAX call, but I've checked, and the showEvents function is correctly creating the list items, so it's not hanging.

After reading [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1772), I tried alternative initialization events: pageinit, and even changePage, without success.

Thanks for your help.

p.s. in case it helps, uncommenting that alert() gets the updated list to reformat correctly, without solving the problem. I figure I'd mention it, since I obviously don't understand what's going on.

Comment: u mean page create function is not working

Comment: No, the function completes. The trouble is that the page loading message is never removed, suggesting that the page rendering is never complete.

Comment: SOLVED - Discovered I was using an old version of Jquery (1.4.1) - must've fat-fingered the version number. [Deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) were only introduced in v1.5.

Answer (score 0):

> If u want to run
>   the code only once when your project loaded then use
>   mobileinit. **pageshow** for every view of page and **pagecreate** for first
>   time when pagecreate in your project.

Comment: Thanks Prince kumar, I've tried switching to pageshow, but it didn't make a difference. But since the problem is not only on second and third page loads, that's not too surprising.